# PHP - populate an array with variables by loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to put my variables (the value of these variables) into an array. I have similar variable names, so I try to find a loop-based solution that gives the same output like that:

```
$str1 = "one";
$str2 = "two";
$str3 = "three";

$arr = array($str1, $str2, $str3);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    echo "[", $key, "] = ", $value, "<br/>";
}
```

For the loop -based solution I tried this way but it doesn't let insert values into the array:

```
$str1 = "one";
$str2 = "two";
$str3 = "three";

function arrayDefine($varName, $max) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; ++$i){
        echo "$", $varName, $i;
        if ($i < $max){
            echo ", ";
        }
    }
}

$arrItems = arrayDefine(str, 3);
$arr = array($arrItems);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    echo "[", $key, "] = ", $value, "<br/>";
}
```

The output of the first code block is:

```
[0] = one
[1] = two
[2] = three
```

but the second displays:

```
$str1, $str2, $str3[0] =
```

What should I change/use in order to get the same result as with the first (not loop-based) solution?

Comment: Um... It doesn't insert values into the array because you didn't create an array with the values.  All your function does is echo some stuff.  You have to actually create an array and return it if you want one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to understand is the difference between printing some information to the output (eg. `echo`) and assigning values to variables.

Your function just prints variable names to the output. However, these are **strings**. String is not equal to a piece of code once the program is running. This is the very basics of any sort of programming, and you must not try to do anything until **variables** are perfectly clear to you.

###Using [`$GLOBALS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Now a solution. Since your variables are **global**, you can access them via php's `$GLOBALS` array. This would look like this:

```
$str1 = "a";
$str2 = "b";
$str3 = "c";

function createArray($name, $count) {
    $return_array  = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $return_array[$name.($i+1)] = $GLOBALS[$name.($i+1)];
    }
    return $return_array;
} 

print_r(createArray("str", 3));
```

Generally, what you're doing is absurd. If you wan't to store some data so that all the data can be accessed, start with an array:

```
array("a", "b", "c");
or
array("str1"=>"a", ...);
```

###Using [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)
Also, many beginners tend to like the "*evil*" function. You could do it too. `eval()` turns a **string** to a piece of code. But, it's always a bad solution and I've always learned a better one when I learned more about programming. However, you can't know everything from the beginning, so here is a way how to produce most dangerous and insecure codes:

function createArray($name, $count) {
$return_array  = array();
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
eval("global $".$name.($i+1));  //Ask global scope to provide this variable
$return_array[$name.($i+1)] = eval("$".$name.($i+1));
}
return $return_array;
}

**This is really dangerous and will cause trouble.**

###Using `$$` syntax
I think that `$$` approach [proposed by ManiacTwister](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21393941/607407) is the best. You can even turn a complicated string to a variable:

```
echo ${"static_text" . $string};
```

However, again, why not use arrays? This features should serve for debug purposes.

###Note on variable scopes.
However, the **[variable scopes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)** might be confusing, see an example:

```
$x = 666;
function printvar($name) {
     global $$name;  //Get the variable from global scope t the function scope
     echo $$name; //if $name = "x" this evaluates into echo $x
     echo "\n";  //New line
}
printvar("x");  //Prints 666


function aFunction() {
    $x = 13;  //This $x only exists betvween {} and has nothing to do with global $x = 666
    printvar("x");  //Still prints 666!
}
```

Comment: I was halfway through writing this same thing.  I agree that anyone who does not understand the difference between strings and variables should stop what they are doing and educate themselves first.

Comment: I started to learn PHP as my first programming language few weeks before. :)

Comment: There is no other way to learn programming than programming, however some basics must be clear before you start doing anything more than `1+1=2`.

Answer (score 2):

Even if its not best practice, this should work:

```
$str1 = "one";
$str2 = "two";
$str3 = "three";

function arrayDefine($varName, $max) {
    $items = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; ++$i){
        $var = $varName.$i;
        global $$var;
        $items[$i] = $$var;
    }
    return $items;
}

$arr= arrayDefine('str', 3);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    echo "[", $key, "] = ", $value, "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, because of scoping issues, you have to use globals to do that function.  "Not best practice" against "the only way to use your idea" typically means "find some better idea."

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Unles it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayFunction()
{
    $str1 = "one";
    $str2 = "two";
    $str3 = "three";
    $array = array($str1, $str2, $str3);


    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        echo "[", $key, "] = ", $value, "<br/>";

    }

}

arrayFunction();
```

Comment: Yes I see what you did there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
$str1 = 'one';
$str2 = 'two';
$str2 = 'three';

for($i=1;$i<100;$i++){
  $varName = 'str' . $i;
  $returnArray[$varName] = $$varName;
}
```

However, if you are making a function, remember, that it won't have access to $str1, $str2, etc...  Because they are in the GLOBAL scope, not the function scope (and unlike most languages ?! (Atleast the ones I know)) GLOBALs are not accessible within a function unless you say "global".

So you'll need to use Tomas' Code.