# How to populate an array dynamicaly using a loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, oop, for-loop

How to populate an array dynamicaly using a for loop in PHP?

eg: Here is an array...

```
    static protected $db_columns = [' ',' '];
```

... and here is the for loop

```
    $qcount = 4;
    for($i=1; $i<=$qcount; $i++) {
```

The array should become

```
     static protected $db_columns = ['1','2',3','4'];
```

Depending on the $qcount the array should expand. Please help.

Comment: Start with an empty array `$db_columns = []` and add items with `$db_columns[] = $value`. It will expand by itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - populate an array with variables by loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393760/php-populate-an-array-with-variables-by-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can initialize array like this

```
$db_columns = array();
```

add value using a loop

```
$qcount = 4;
for($i=1; $i<=$qcount; $i++) {
 array_push($db_columns,$i);
}
```

and after loop, you can check with printing array

```
var_dump($db_columns);
```